# How to get/post with axios?

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios, ecmascript-2017

I want to make a get and later a post request with axios (should be async).

Here is the code:

```
async getJSONAsync()
    {
       await app.get('https://*****.io/index.php?/api/v2/get_case/5892', {
            headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
            auth: {
                username : '************',
                password : '*********************'
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

The question is - how should I store baseURL and other options like headers, auth info, body(data) and when I get back the result - how to use it with another function - like post with some data from previous get request response? 
I'm lost here. Please, help.

Comment: "how should I store baseURL and other options like headers, auth info, body(data) " — is something wrong with the Axios documentation?

Comment: "like post with some data from previous get request response" — Exactly the same way as any other function. Change `getJSONAsync()` so it accepts arguments.

Comment: You should probably work through an introductory JavaScript tutorial before diving into a complex library that uses promises.

Comment: I'm new to javascript. 
Should I create like separate js file with options, that I would pass into this function? How should it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const axios = require('axios');


const getRandomDogPicture = async () => {
    const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random",
        timeout: 1000,
        headers: {
            'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'
        }
    });

    let result = await instance.get().then(result => result.data);
    return result;
}

const func = async () => {
    let ans = await getRandomDogPicture();
    console.log(ans)
}
console.log(func());
```

Comment: where to add authorization, content-type header?

Comment: @LittleJohnny ?